# Foundry Wordpress Theme navigation bar overlapping WooCommerce store pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, navbar

I am working on a Wordpress website which uses the Foundry Wordpress theme. I am noticing some very strange behaviour on two of the pages - the shop front and the individual product pages, provided through Woocommerce. It doesn't however, happen on the cart or checkout pages, only these two.

Normally, the page content should sit straight below the nav bar. On these pages, however, the nav bar seems to overlay on the page content, i.e. the page title section starts at the top of the loaded page, as does the navigation bar section.

I have tried adding a fixed margin and a fixed padding through custom css, to the top of the title bar, to at least apply a temporary fix, along these lines, although this doesn't work either:

```
    .main-container .page-title {
      padding-top: 270px !important;
    }
```

Here's the link to the site (you just need to head to Shop > Vouchers to see what I mean).

https://elevationairsports.com/?cmp_bypass=c744dd4c300c0dfe746a5cf17ea0c4b8

I would be grateful if someone could help me identify why these issues are happening and only on the shop front and product pages. It's like something is pinning the content to the top of the page and ignoring the nav bar. The site uses the WP Bakery page builder. Thanks!

EDIT

So, I have just done a 'test' by telling Woocommerce that the store page is a different page. Once that setting is removed from the page (accessible when you go to Shop > Vouchers from the nav menu) everything works fine. When the page is re-selected as the Woocommerce shop page, it appears again, so it has to be an effect caused by the way Woocommerce interacts with the Foundry theme, although what, I don't know.

Comment: Check this screenshot - https://ibb.co/bPttjG1 . In page templates you have min-height. In shop templates you dont. Would be better .nav-container{min-height:270px;}

Comment: @MartinMirchev that does seem to have worked, thanks! It is such a small thing that I didn't notice it. I'd be happy to mark it as a correct answer if you want to write that as an answer.

Comment: This is strongly only to you solution so noone would benefit from my answer :) Happy coding !

Comment: Fair enough, thanks! Since you mentioned it, I have realised it is actually a fault of the theme. Basically, it gives the option of having a transparent header or not. For a transparent header, it basically removes the .nav-container{min-height:270px;} bit, so it sits over the image. For these two pages, it seems to be stuck on the transparent header, which is why you see no min height. oh well, I'll find a solution, I'm sure! :)